# How to decrease Android Screen Resolution to support low memory

Tags: android

Hi i am facing low memory issue in my game due to large number of bitmaps.i am recycling them as well but is there any way to decrease display resolution of screen(game) to support low memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a BitmapOptions if i'm not mistaken one of them does just what Diadistis suggests.
Take a look on that class it might help.
Are you working in the java realm or NDK ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do pixel doubling. This will effectively reduce the screen resolution to half.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, and that wouldn't really help anyway. Why don't you use lower-resolution bitmaps/textures instead?